# Catching "Cancel" in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pathlib, filedialog

I have a script that opens a prompt window for a user to select a directory before performing some other tasks. If the user selects "Cancel", I want the program to display an appropriate message and exit the program.

However, I cannot get this to work. Here is what I've tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pathlib
from tkinter import filedialog

print('\nScript Initialised\nOpening File Dialog Window...\n')
# Define Functions here
def chooseDir():
    print('Choose folder 1')
    global outputfolder
    outputfolder = pathlib.Path(filedialog.askdirectory(title="Output Folder", initialdir='C:\\'))
    if outputfolder == '.':
        print('No folder selected. Program exiting.')
        quit()
    root.withdraw()

def openFile():
    print('Choose folder 2')
    global inputfolder
    inputfolder = pathlib.Path(filedialog.askdirectory(title="Import Folder", initialdir='C:\\'))
    if inputfolder == '.':
        print('No folder selected. Program exiting.')
        quit()
    root.withdraw()

# Create Tkinter menu
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
openFile()
root.withdraw()
chooseDir()
root.destroy()
root.mainloop()

print(outputfolder)
print(inputfolder)
```

I've also tried an empty string of '' and that doesn't appear to print the message in the if-statement.

Comment: Consider printing the value to see what it is in case of a cancel

Comment: I have, the 2 print statements at the bottom indicate a period when the user clicks "Cancel". However this doesn't return the correct message in the IF.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley So how do you catch it? If I change it to an empty string, it still doesn't work

Comment: You print No folder selected if the user selects the current folder, that's what `if outputfolder == '.':` does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined behavior of `askdirectory` is to return the empty string if you press cancel. You need to check for that. What you're doing instead is converting that empty string to a `Path` object before doing the check. You shouldn't do that until after you've verified that it's not the empty string.

```
path = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Output Folder", initialdir='C:\\')
if path == "":
    print("No folder selected. Program exiting.")
    quit()
outputfolder = pathlib.Path(path)
```